# How can the Silverlight BarChart's origin (X, Y = 0, 0) be set to the upper-left corner?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-toolkit

I have a Silverlight Chart with a BarSeries, with the bars set horizontally.  The data origin starts in the lower, right corner.  The source data is also bound to a ListBox.  The sorts appear different on the screen when comparing the Chart and ListBox.  Here is an example of what it looks like:

**Chart**

> Item4 ========
>
> Item3 =====
>
> Item2 ===========
>
> Item1 ==
>
> Item0 =======

**ListBox**

> Item0
>
> Item1
>
> Item2
>
> Item3
>
> Item4

How can I set the data for the chart to start from the upper, left corner?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your BarSeries and ListBox objects inside of a DataGrid? It seems that using a DataGrid would help you lay out your items better.